# My Android phone stuck at optimizing apps again and again

Tags: cyanogenmod, micromax-yu-yureka

My Yu Yureka with Cyanogen Mod is Optimizing apps again and again but not starting. Is there a way to fix this?
Is tjere a way I can somehow enter safe mode and delete few apps??  Please help.

Comment: Possibly related, as you also use a custom ROM (CyanogenMod): [Fairphone Open stuck in “optimizing app” loop after OS update](/q/162631/16575). Very likely related: [Yu Yuphoria YU5010 is stuck in “Optimize apps # of #” loop](/q/183262/16575). Also related: [Android continues rebooting and 'optimizing'](/q/114997/16575). More candidates [by this search](/search?q=optimizing+apps) on our site.

Comment: Thanks for response..!!  I finally found a solution. Writing in answer

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution and thats when the apps are being optimised..when the phone reaches to optimising last 1 or 2 apps (for example: optimising 99 of 100) press and hold volume down key untill the phone starts; the phone boots into safe mode and we can remove a few apps and take data backup to PC. Now when rebooted it starts normally..
Thanks everyone for response..!

Comment: Wow, that really works..!!  Saved me... thank you soo much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to hard reset your mobile but this will delete all your data and apps. To hard reset YU Yureka Android smartphone follow the below mentioned steps.

1. Shutdown the mobile.
2. Enter into Recovery Mode by pressing and holding

   **Volume Up + Volume Down + Power** buttons **simultaneously** until you see YU logo.
                                 **(OR)**
   **Volume Up + Power key** for about **5 seconds** until you see YU logo.
3. Once you are in Recovery Mode, choose wipe data/factory reset and perform the operation.
4. Now choose wipe cache partition and perform the operation.
5. Now finally choose Wipe media and perform operation.
6. Once done, reboot your device.

That’s all now YU Yureka will boot with factory settings loaded and you have successfully hard reset YU Yureka.

Comment: Gvtha: You describe a [factory-reset](/tags/factory-reset/info) but name it [hard-reset](/tags/hard-reset/info). A common mis-naming, but a hard-reset is just "a forced reboot/shutdown by removing power" (e.g. by removing the battery and putting it back again) as opposed to a soft-reset (as described by [Shamik's answer](/a/187093/16575)), see [What is hard reset and what is factory reset?](/q/6422/16575) Maybe you want to [edit] your answer and fix that up?

Comment: @izzy definitely a major mis-naming being that a quick Google search [brings up](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&q=hard+reset+definition&oq=&aqs=) some major tech websites, describing, hard reset as factory reset

Comment: @Abochur but second to "android virus", you must admit – or we wouldn't have that many "anti virus" apps in the stores ;) // Some background: "soft reset": Ctrl-Alt-Del. "hard reset": that "Windows repair button" on your computer (which does … cut the power while pressed, yupp). // If enough people calling a pig pidgeon, that pig still doesn't fly :)