# Bootloop in Yureka - Rescue data?

Tags: boot-loop, data-recovery, micromax-yu-yureka

I have an old YU Yureka piece, and it has gone into a boot loop.

What happens is, **CYANOGEN** logo comes up in the beginning, and then "**Android is starting - Optimizing x/123 apps**" comes up. As x reaches 123, the phone reboots again, and the same thing starts all over again.

One thing note worthing is that it's not always x/123. Sometimes it goes till x/9, x/29, x/27, x/120 etc.. It's not in any decreasing/increasing order. I have let this thing run many times, and for many hours (I was hopeful it would just magically show up my home screen after x reached whatever).

But thanks to my hopefulness, Once it so happened that when it was x/9, and x reached 9 and the phone rebooted, it did not do the same thing again but *the phone started*!! But only until I connected my cable to get all the data, it rebooted again and the boot loop continued from x/123 this time.

Other things you might want to know:

- My phone is pattern protected (locked)
- It is not rooted
- ADB was not set up from the settings
- **AND I AM CONCERNED ABOUT MY DATA**, so no wiping/formatting of Internal SD card!

Oh, and Cyanogen rescue mode has the following options:

- Reboot system now
- Apply update
- Wipe data/factory reset (I want to **avoid** this)
- Wipe cache partition (I have tried this)
- Wipe media
- Reboot to bootloader
- Power [???]
- [???] logs

Sorry for [???] as whatever is written there I can't read it due to a screen display problem.

Right now I am just waiting for that magic to happen again, hopefully if the home screen comes up, this time instead of connecting it with cable, I will first remove the lock pattern, and set up ADB. But I have no clue how it happened last time, or how/when will it happen again.

Also I am unable to connect with fast boot, as I guess we need ADB set up for that. Is that right? `adb devices` does not list my device. I haven't really worked much with fast boot, flashing, etc. But I will be comfortable to follow instructions. *All I want is to rescue my data.*

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Same issue at [My Android phone stuck at optimizing apps again and again](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187072/16575) with 2 possible solutions, Vijay. Please check there :)

Comment: Glad to read – though I only was pointing ;)