# Yuphoria optimizing apps loop

Tags: boot-loop, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I have YU Yuphoria 5010...When i start  Mobile it shows CYANOGEN then "optimizing apps ..." and then it complete and again starts optimizing.

My main concern is internal data... I don't want to wipe it out. Please help me out as soon.

Also my mobile is not rooted and does not have twrp.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution to this  problem. In one of post it is mentioned that start phone in safe mode. And i do so and really it WORKS!!!!

Just press volume down key after first time optimizing ends and then it will boot in safe mode.[Here is detailed answer that i mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187072/my-android-phone-stuck-at-optimizing-apps-again-and-again/194197#194197)

Answer (score -1):

I was once struck in a boot loop and when I  went to service centre, they found that it was not a software but a battery problem. Try getting it changed.

Comment: Thanks ansh. I had do that but in my case it is not battery issue. I have heard many of device had battery issue.